# Count Incrementer not setting state in react-hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've a list of `Meal` components, which I render inside a `MealList` component. For each meal I want to pass a count value. This is my code.

```
const MealList = (props) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    return (
        <div style={{width: '70%'}}>
            <h3 style={{color: 'grey', fontSize: '1.4em', fontWeight: '700', marginBottom: '1em'}}><FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faPlusCircle} style={{color: '#007bff', marginRight: '0.5em'}}/> ADD MEAL</h3>
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Meal</th>
                    <th>Calories</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {props.meals.map(meal => (<Meal count={setCount(count + 1)} meal={meal}/>))}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>

    )
};
export default MealList;
```

This breaks the code, how do `setState` correctly ?

Comment: Did you try to pass the array index to count prop?

Comment: @AlexanderVidaurreArroyo this should help, but how do I access the index property inside a map function?

Comment: With the second param.

Comment: Seems like i misunderstood the question. Sorry !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the count props as an index, then you don't need use state, you can pass the array index for this purpose:

```
{props.meals.map((meal, index) => (<Meal count={index +1} meal={meal}/>))}
```

Answer (score -1):

onChange={ () => setCount(count+1) } count={count}

You need to add on change or similar event to update count. This is the sample code